# Get peak point [up and bottom] from accelerometer data using python

Tags: python

I am a newbie in signal processing, In here, I want to ask how to get peak point from a accelerometer data. Visualization of my data is like this one:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data as a set of coordinates or data points for the above visualization, it will be as simple as using the built-in `min` and `max` functions:

If your data is a simple array of numbers, e.g. `arr = [12, 33, -17, ...]`:

```
peak = max(arr)
trough = min(arr)

print peak, trough
```

will print `33, -17`

If it is a list of coordinates, e.g. `coords = [(0, 12), (1, 33), (2, -17), ...]`:

```
peak = max(coords, key=lambda x: x[1])
trough = min(coords, key=lambda x: x[1])

print peak, trough
```

will print `(1, 33), (2, -17)`

These functions take a `key` argument that is a function to apply to the elements of the list to compare them. In this example, we just extract the 2nd element of the tuple.

reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max